# Problema guardando datos en arrays

Tags: java, java-swing

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicacion que guarda todas las palabras de un texto en un arraylist.Tengo un problema y es que no se almacenan las palabras.Lo he comprobado con System.out.println();.Espero que en la salida me ponga las palabras pero me da error, me pone esto

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   12.

Os dejo mi código a ver si alguien puede descubrir que le pasa.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String texto = txt.getText();
    String anadir = "";
    ArrayList<String> palabras = new ArrayList();


    for (int x = 0; x <= texto.length(); x++) {
        if (texto.charAt(x) == ' ' || texto.charAt(x) == '.') {
            palabras.add(anadir);
            anadir = "";
        } else { 
            anadir += texto.charAt(x);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Intenta cambiar `<=` a `<`

Comment: si o anda hasta length -1 . El tamaño de un string es la cantidad de caracteres, pero el primero no es el 1, es el 0, entonces al recorrerlo tenes que ir hasta uno menos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recuerda que los arreglos en java se acceden comenzando con el índice 0 y terminando por el índice 'cantidad de elementos - 1'. En tu caso tiene una condición de parada en el ciclo `for` que asume como índice válido la cantidad de elementos (`x <= texto.length()`). Esto provoca que cuando intentas acceder a ese índice, este se encuentra fuera del rango aceptado y se lanza la excepción `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

La solución es muy simple, cambia la condición de parada de `for` por esta: `x < texto.length()`

Comment: Por el momento si hago el debug en la lista ya veo que se almacenan los datos, pero al imprimirlos me da error ,y, simplemente añadí esto a continuacíon del for                                                                                          for (int y = 0; y < palabras.size(); y++) {
            System.out.println(palabras.get(y));
        }

Comment: Qué error? Todo parece bien.

Comment: Un error de hace tiempo,pero ya arreglé todo

Comment: Excelente! Saludos.